# background issue with styles and themes

Tags: android, themes, styles, android-theme

in attrs I have

```
<attr name="bzz" format="color" />
```

then in theme

```
<style name="mytheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="bzz">@color/aaa</item>
</style>
```

and in the code
this works great

```
tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.aaa);
```

but when I do this it gives me an error

```
tv.setBackgroundResource(R.attr.bzz);
```

I do not understand what is the problem, my logic is that I set the bzz as reference to color so that should work fine, but it does not :)
it says like `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f010008`
but I do not understand what resource can't be found ?

I am sure that the color is there sins if I set it directly it works great, what exacly is the thing that is not linked correctly

Thanks

Comment: Have a similar issue. Logically it is sound. Don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

You need to resolve the `attr` to get the corresponding `color`'s resource id. Then you can set the `TextView`'s background resource to the obtained resource id.

Example code:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.bzz, typedValue, true);
tv.setBackgroundResource(typedValue.resourceId);
```