# Android  setting LinearLayout background programmatically

Tags: android, layout

I have a situation where I need to set a background on a LinearLayout programatically.

In my layout, I am setting my background using `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator", but I want to set this programatically:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLayoutId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" >
```

I've tried using:

```
Drawable d = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.attr.activatedBackgroundIndicator);
rootLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

But it crashes. Any ideas?

Edit: I had also tried using:

```
rootLayout.setBackgroundResource(android.R.attr.activatedBackgroundIndicator);

10-08 15:23:19.018: E/AndroidRuntime(11133): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x10102fd
```

Comment: posting logcat helps a lot to find the solution for the crash

Comment: Next time, add the logcat. I think your minSdk is not 11 and you are running this on a device with api <11 which will crash it because activatedBackgroundIndicator is available since api 11. If this is not the case, post the logcat for help

Comment: which API level you are using?

Comment: that means that the resource you trying to find is not found, if you want to get a dRawable , you should get it from R.drawable ( or android.R.drawable ) and not from android.R.attr

Comment: I know activatedBackgroundIndicator doesn't exist on pre-11, I have a check for that, that's not the issue.

Comment: Houcine: that was precisely my question.

Comment: Are you running on a custom rom maybe?

Comment: Nope, was running on stock LG Optimus one ROM.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it using this piece of code.

The android.R.attr.* are pointers to the  in a theme and not to the actual drawable resource defined. You have to use the [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html) to access the id.

```
theView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_job_favorited, null);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { android.R.attr.activatedBackgroundIndicator });
  int resource = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
  //first 0 is the index in the array, second is the   default value
  a.recycle();

  theView.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(resource));
}
```

I used this in my custom list adapter when detects SDK upper and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for solution! But need use `setBackgroundDrawable` on pre-JellyBean.

Comment: There is a simpler method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14524876/1521536), and *without* hardcoding…

Answer (score 6):

try this line

```
rootLayout.setBackgroundResource(d);
```

instead of

```
rootLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
rootLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea doing it the way the accepted answer tells you to. The problem is that you also need to call the list's `onItemCheckedStateChanged` to update what's needed (the action bar title for example).

In that case all you need to do is simply call `getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);` when the item is checked and `getListView().setItemChecked(position, false);` when it's not checked.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following code.

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutImage);
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

`TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
 context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackgroun  d, outValue, true);
 view.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);`