# Cant set the Linear layout background from a path

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

my code is this

```html
 ll.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath(new ImageLoader().fullPath+"/desiredFilename.png"));
```

ll is the object of my linear layout ,is this the correct method

```html
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new ImageLoader().fullPath+"/desiredFilename.png");
              Resources res=getResources();
              BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res,bitmap);
              ll.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
```

i also used this code but dosent work 
shows error noSuchMethods

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781501/android-setting-linearlayout-background-programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781501/android-setting-linearlayout-background-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
  ll.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

instead of

```
  ll.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
```

Comment: thanks for the help,i have tried it before and its works perfectly then why am i asking this question means ll.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable); seem to be deprecated so im looking for a new solution

Comment: @AmeenMaheen Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/android-set-background-drawable-programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/android-set-background-drawable-programmatically)

Comment: :-) what will i do  if i have to load the image from the sd card like the code in my question.?